# How to set Wi-Fi Direct password?

Tags: android, wifip2p

I am creating an access point on android using Wi-Fi Direct. The name of the access point and the password are generated automatically when I call createGroup on my WifiP2pManager. How can I set the password myself? Is it even possible?

Comment: Have you find any solution about this?